# DocuSign enable Print & Sign in OTHER ACTIONS

Tags: java, docusignapi, digital-signature, docusigncompositetmplts

I am using DocuSign java api to create envelop and send the document for signature to multiple signers and it's working fine & all the signers can sign the document successfully.

If I am sending envelop from **DocuSign** UI using existing templates then only the option **Print & Sign** comes in **OTHER ACTIONS**

I want to enable option **Print & Sign** in **OTHER ACTIONS** using **DocuSign** Java Api

I have found & enabled the Admin - Signing Settings

```
Allow recipients to sign on paper

Allow senders to override sign on paper
```

[image]

But still while any signer is signing the document **Print & Sign**  not coming in **OTHER ACTIONS**

```
InputStream is = wordReader.getContentInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copy(is, os);  
        byte[] bytes = os.toByteArray();

        Signable pdf = new Signable(fileName, bytes, MimetypeMap.MIMETYPE_OPENXML_WORDPROCESSING);

        List<DSAccount> accounts = ds.get_accounts();
        DSAccount first_acct = accounts.get(0);

        SimpleAddressLabel address_label = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < signers.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject signer = (JSONObject) signers.get(i);
            String name = signer.getString("name").toString();
            String signerUserName = signer.getString("userName").toString();

            NodeRef signerNode = personService.getPerson(signerUserName);
            String email = nodeService.getProperty(signerNode, ContentModel.PROP_EMAIL).toString();

            int id = i+1;
            int order = Integer.parseInt(signer.getString("order"));

            if(i == 0) {
                address_label = new SimpleAddressLabel(name, email);
            } else {
                DSRecipient signerRec = new DSRecipient(name,email,id,order);
                address_label.add_signer(signerRec);
            }
        }

        DSTrackingNumber send_results = ds.send_single_document(first_acct, address_label, pdf,"Signature-"+FilenameUtils.removeExtension(fileName), "Mr. "+fullName+" needs your signature.");
```

The java api code I am using to send envelop for signing.

Please guide me that how to enable that option.

Answer (score 1):

Vikash, This should work from the API just like it works from the UI.
Would you mind downloading and trying our example code for Java? you can get it here - https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant this would help to try to isolate the issue (the code you posted in the question is not complete and is missing how you are setting the envelope using the DocuSign API)

Comment: Thanks for your response.
You are right. it should work.

I tried the above example in my local it's running but it's giving error of Redirect uri which may not be configured correctly I have added the same in API & Keys > Additional settings > Redirect URIs > http://localhost:8080. still getting the redirect uri error.

Comment: are you sure you configured the correct uri? are you sure you are using account-d.docusign.com (and not account.docusign.com) ?

Comment: yes, it's account-d.docusign.com - after login --> https://admindemo.docusign.com/api-integrator-key